# Induced Emf in turning coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

[image]

From the photo, why is the emf zero? Wont it cut field lines when it rotate? When it cut field lines wont there be a change in magnetic flux? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic flux is the area integral of the flux density ($B$) component **perpendicular** to the area (in this case the coil area). Since the flux density is always **parallel** to the coil area in the example, the flux is zero, and with it the change of flux, which results in zero EMF.

Thus, the conductor cutting field lines is not relevant for induction, but rather the area inside the loop cutting field lines **at some angle** (which it doesn't in the example provided).